# Expect Capybara to not find something?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

Say I have a "log in" button in my app, which can be enabled / disabled by the admins. What's the best way to test that this button is *not* rendered when the log in function is disabled? (The page should render fine, but the button should not be there.)

I can't seem to find a way to `expect` the `find` to fail. Am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: Expect `not_to` instead of `to`?

Answer (score 6):

Well, if your button has a `class` or an `id` then you can check if the page does not include that `class` or `id`:

```
expect(page).not_to have_selector "#botton_id" or ".button_class"
```

or if the name of your button is unique you could check if that doesn't appear on the page:

```
expect(page).not_to have_content('Button Name')
```

Answer (score 4):

If you would have checked for the existence of the button by doing

```
expect(page).to have_button('log in')
```

then you can do either of

```
expect(page).not_to have_button('log in')
expect(page).to have_no_button('log in')
```

to make sure the 'log in' button doesn't exist - similar can be done with have_link, have_field, have_selector, etc.  If you're not using RSpec then then something along the lines of

```
page.assert_no_selector(:button, 'log in')
```

or

```
assert page.has_no_button?('log in')
```

would do what you want